# Problems automating sending mail through a bash shell script

Tags: bash, sendmail

**command:**

```
echo "define(`SMART_HOST',`smtp.server.ac.in')" >>/etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

**Output :**

```
-bash: command substitution: line 1:
 unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-bash: command substitution: line 2: 
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: The error says it all: you don't use matching start and end quotations within your `define` string. What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your command fails, because Bash tries to interpret "`". Add "\" and it will work:

```
echo "define(\`SMART_HOST',\`smtp.server.ac.in')" >>/etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

Btw: The title, content, tag of your post are three different topics.

Some more details: Bash will treat everything enclosed in double quotes ("") as as one string, but also replace variables with their content, execute code inside backticks ("`") and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you got that command from [this site’s guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-sendmail-as-a-smart-host/) or something similar. That command is not magic; all that command is doing is telling Bash to append—via `>>`—the following text:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`smtp.server.ac.in')
```

To the end of this file:

```
/etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

If that `>>` appending method is choking things up, an alternative method of setting that value is to just open up `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` in your favorite terminal text editor—such as [`nano`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nano)—and add/edit that `define()` right in there like this:

```
nano /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

Then just add/edit/append that `define(`SMART_HOST',`smtp.server.ac.in')` into that file, follow the rest of the steps of that tutorial—or whatever guide you are using—and you should be good to go.